# Convert ASM to C?

Tags: c, assembly, 64-bit

I am trying to convert the following ASM to C but I can't understand what the jump statements are doing. Can someone help me as to what exactly is going on?

```
func_a:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    testq   %rdx, %rdx
    js  .L3
    movslq  %edi, %rdi
    movslq  %esi, %rsi
    addq    %rdi, %rsi
    cmpq    %rdx, %rax
    jg  .L4
    rep ret
.L3:
    movl    $0, %eax
    ret
.L4:
    movq    %rdx, %rax
    .p2align 4,,4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: Which part of the jumps is unclear? Have you read the instruction set reference telling you what each does? Also, are you sure you copied the function correctly? `rax` seems to be used uninitialized (at least as per standard calling convention).

Comment: The first jump goes to `.L3` is `RDX` is positive. The second goes to `.L4` if `RDX` is greater than `RAX`.

Comment: @Barmar you got both of those reversed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`js` jumps to `.L3` if the sign (MSB) of `%rdx` is set (i.e. if `%rdx` is negative).

`jg` jumps to `.L4` if `%rax` is greater than `%rdx` (AT&T syntax, the operands are reversed).

The rest of the code sign extends `%edi` and `%esi` to 64 bits and then adds them together.

Comment: I tried replicating the code, but I get L4. and L1. instead.

Comment: @VBoi the label numbers assigned by the compiler are unpredictable and so is the exact assembly generated.  You can't expect to exactly reconstruct source code from assembly code such that the compiler compiles your reconstruction to the same assembly.